# Passing PHP xdebug context through file_get_contents

Tags: php, xdebug, file-get-contents

I'm using `file_get_contents()` to query another part of my PHP application.  I'm comfortable constructing a 'POST' or even multipart query to simulate a file upload with this, but what I can't seem to figure out is how to make the processing of the `file_get_contents()` hook into my existing xdebug session (which is working, since I can step through the query processing).

I've tried passing the `XDEBUG_SESSION` cookie from the current request being processed but it doesn't seem to do what I want.

Comment: Would it be simpler to directly call the functions in php, rather than dealing with http requests (or IO)?

Comment: Part of what I want to test is the HTTP layer, so yes I could but it wouldn't get me all of what I want.